# Setting up Global Metadata Navigation on 2013

Tags: 2013, navigation, managed-metadata, managed-navigation

Found some articles about using the Managed Term Stores to create cross-site collection global navigation in SharePoint 2013. Most excellent, and seems simple enough. However, I'm encountering an error trying to set it up in my test environment.

I can get the navigation working if I use a term set scoped to the site collection. However, after I create a navigation term set in central administration, and try to select it on a publishing site, I get the following error when saving the changes:
**The current user has insufficient permissions to perform this operation**

I've tried expanding the permissions in every way that I can think of, but haven't had any luck. Looking in the ULS logs, I only see the permission error, with no other indicators. Anyone have any thoughts?

Comment: Have you tried making the user the Term Store Administrator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was finally able to get it to attach when I added my own account as the Term Group Manager using Central Administration. Thanks to Vardhaman.